# Template url, number with 'L'

Tags: python, django

I've got following code in my template:

```
{% url "app.views.details" d.id %}
```

Normally it works good, but now I have problem that in the end of ID is 'L', so I'm getting exception:

> Reverse for 'app.views.details' with arguments '(4L,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

What is wrong with that id now?

EDIT:
Here is my url.conf:

```
url(r'^detailed-stats/(?P<id>\d+)/', 'app.views.details', name='details'),
```

Comment: It's nothing wrong with it. Python appends a L because it's of type long.

Comment: but how to fix it in template?

Comment: Are you saying the reverse url lookup works when `id` is *not* a long int? What does your url registration for `app.views.details` look like?

Comment: What does the declaration of `app.views.details` look like?

Comment: There is nothing to fix here. Your diagnosis of the problem is wrong. You should show the relevant URLconf.

Comment: does your view `details` take a parameter `id` ?

Comment: yes, details take id as parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`long` numbers works with `\d+` pattern, try to use the `name` param of your route instead:

```
{% url "details" id=d.id %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your URL has the name 'details', but in the template you are trying to use a URL named 'app.views.detail'. This is incorrect, as this is actually the view which will be processing the URL.  Change your template to be

```
{% url "details" id=d.id %}
```